# View requests between Comm server and client?

Tags: windows, service

Is there anyway to view the actual content of a request sent between a client and service? Specifically I know the Server UUID and the Process ID and I would like to be able to view what requests the client makes corresponding to various client side actions.

I thought the two communicated via HTTP, but I've been trying to view this info using Wireshark and haven't found any relation between requests made on the client side and those caught by Wireshark.

Suggestions or reading material would be appreciated, I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: "Server UUID"?  So its a COM server/client or ... ?

Comment: Having read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835(v=vs.85).aspx) I believe that it is, that label seems fairly general though. @AlexK.